# first column in dataframe lost after grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, primary-key

Please excuse me if this question is too n00bish, I am brand new to Python and need to use it for work, which unfortunately means diving into higher level stuff without first understanding the basics...

I have a massive CSV with text transcripts which I read into a pandas dataframe. These transcripts are broken down into IDs and the ID's must be grouped to get a singular record for each interaction as they are broken apart into segments in the original database they come from. The format is something like this:

```
    ID      TEXT
    1       This is the beginning of a convo
    1        heres the middle
    1       heres the end of the convo
    2       this is the start of another convo...etc.
```

I used this code to group by ID and create singular records:

```
    df1 = df.groupby('ID').text.apply(' '.join)
```

This code worked great but now I am stuck with a series (?) that no longer recognizes the index "ID", I think it's been merged with the text or something. When I use to_frame() the problem remains. I am wondering how I might separate the ID again and use that to index the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groupby will return groupby-ed column as the index. Looking at your code this is what I see.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2], 
                  'TEXT':['This is the beginning of a convo', 'heres the 
                          middle', 'heres the end of the convo', 'this is the 
                          start of another convo...etc.']})
df1 = df.groupby('ID').TEXT.apply(' '.join)
print(df1)

ID
1    This is the beginning of a convo heres the mid...
2    this is the start of another convo...etc.
Name: TEXT, dtype: object
```

You can take the series `df1` and re-index it if you want the ID as a column in a dataframe, or move on with it as an index to the series which can be handy depending on what your next steps will be.

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print(df1)

    ID  TEXT
0   1   This is the beginning of a convo heres the mid...
1   2   this is the start of another convo...etc.
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I still get the same output of Name: TEXT, dtype: object and a KeyError exception when I try to pull ID after resetting the index.

Comment: Basically after resetting the index if I do print(df1["ID"]) this throws a keyerror the same as before. If I did that same thing before grouping by ID it would return a list of the IDs.

Comment: Did you assign the df1.reset_index() to an object.  It does not do the change in place I clarified that in my answer edit. If you do the `df1 = df.group('ID').TEXT.apply(' '.join)` then you can call the df1 indexes using either the ordinal location, or the index value.  Example, returning the conversation to ID 1 `df1.loc[1]` returns `'This is the beginning of a convo heres the middle heres the end of the convo'`  The 'ID' becomes the name of the index in this case so you cant directly call int df1['ID'], but can return the index of a series or dataframe with df1.index